# SCRIPT ERROR: @qb-scoreboard-main/server.lua:34: attempt to index a number value (local 'v')

Tags: lua

```
QBCore.Functions.CreateCallback('qb-scoreboard:server:GetPlayersArrays',
  function(source, cb)
    local players = {}
    for k, v in pairs(QBCore.Functions.GetQBPlayers()) do
      players[v.PlayerData.source] = {}
      players[v.PlayerData.source].permission = QBCore.Functions.IsOptin(v.PlayerData.source)
    end
    cb(players)
  end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`v` is a number value. you cannot index number values. `v.PlayerData` is an invalid operation.

Find out why you think `v` is a table and why it is a number instead.

Either make sure it is not a number or that you don't index it.